# Rasterio DatasetIOShapeError: Dataset indexes and destination buffer are mismatched

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

I am trying to merge multiple .tiff files into a mosaic using Rasterio.

```
tiles_to_merge = []
for id in tile_ids:
    tile = rasterio.open('../data/planet/' + id + '.tiff')
    tiles_to_merge.append(tile)

mosaic, output = rasterio.merge.merge(tiles_to_merge)
```

But I end up with the following error.

```
---> 14 mosaic, output = rasterio.merge.merge(tiles_to_merge)
DatasetIOShapeError: Dataset indexes and destination buffer are mismatched
```

According to the documentation this error is *"Raised when data buffer shape is a mismatch when reading and writing"*. Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it would seem that not all rasters have the same number of bands.  Either remove the mis-matched rasters, or try passing `indexes` as an integer or list of integers containing the subset of bands that all rasters contain.

https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.merge.html#rasterio.merge.merge